# More than one list element changes when I just need it to change one

Tags: python, list

I am attempting to solve this HackerRank question:

> Given five positive integers, find the minimum and maximum values that
> can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. Then
> print the respective minimum and maximum values as a single line of
> two space-separated long integers.
>
> Example
>
> ```
> arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> ```
>
> The minimum sum is `1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 16` and the maximum sum is `3 + 5 + 7 + 9 = 24`
>
> The function prints
>
> ```
> 16 24
> ```
>
> Input Format
>
> A single line of five space-separated integers.
>
> Sample Input
>
> ```
> 1 2 3 4 5
> ```
>
> Sample Output
>
> ```
> 10 14
> ```

Below is my code:

```
def miniMaxSum(arr):

    n = len(arr)
    results = []
    work_arr = arr

    for i in range(n):
        total = 0

        work_arr[i] = 0

        print(work_arr)

        for y in range(n):
            total = total + work_arr[y]

        # results.append(total)

        work_arr = arr

    # print(results)

miniMaxSum([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Why does it output:

```
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 0, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 0, 0, 4, 5]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 5]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Instead of what I want, which is:

```
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 0, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 0, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 0, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
```

A revolving zero, but instead the zeros keep increasing

Why isn't the line `work_arr = arr` at the end of the iteration resetting the list back to the original that was passed to the function? Why does it keep adding zeros when I want it to just change that one at that index? And I do a reset at the end

Comment: `work_arr = arr` doesn't make a copy of `arr`. Both variables refer to the same array.

Answer (score 0):

`work_arr = arr` copies reference only in python, so the two variables point to the same array and changing one would change the other.

What you want is a deep copy e.g. `work_arr = arr[:]` or `work_arr = list(arr)` that creates a new list in memory with the same values.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Your comment pointed me in the right direction.